# How to convert the coordinates of the mouse on the page to map google coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to convert the coordinates of the mouse on the page to google map coordinates （latlng object）

Answer (score 0):

User `mousemove` and `event.latLng` to detect coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/shagabutdinov/voz2n65a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
      var lat = event.latLng.lat();
      var lng = event.latLng.lng();
      // populate yor box/field with lat, lng
      alert("Lat=" + lat + "; Lng=" + lng);
    });
```

But you use "mouseover" event (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)